# Can we see the shape of an antenna?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, antennas

What I mean is the following: Is it possible from knowing the radiation pattern/frequency distribution of an antenna to calculate the geometric form of that antenna uniquely? My guess would be, that this could be possible in the near field of an antenna, but not anymore in the far field. But maybe it is possible in both case, because the sending and receiving antenna usually have the same shape. So maybe the information about the shape of the antenna is also available in the far field?

Comment: not from the radiation field (Rayleigh region) as it is usually called for it is the far-field and their the waves are plane waves. Recall that small dipoles have essentially the same radiation fields. Maybe it is reconstructible from the near-field (non radiating reactive field - Fresnel region) but even then I am skeptical because almost certainly it is mathematically an ill-posed problem.

Comment: @hyportnex, no antenna radiates uniform plane waves in the far field if you consider the whole radiation pattern over the whole sphere around it.

Comment: @The Photon the antenna does not radiate plane waves but the receive antenna with which you are measuring the radiation receives a plane wave in the *far field*, and to reconstruct the source that is what matters.

Comment: @hyportnex, You'd likely need more than one antenna to measure the far field pattern while maintaining a phase reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can almost calculate the shape of the antenna.  You can calculate everything which is visible from outside, but if there was a closed box structure inside the antenna, you may know nothing about this.

The justification is really simple: holograms.  Holograms capture the shape of a 3d object radiating energy from a coherent light source by capturing its interference patterns at a distance.  Light waves are electromagnetic radiation, so we can think of our antenna as an object "illuminated" by a constant source.

Of course, to do this we will need phase information, not just gain.  If all you have is a diagram of gain vs. direction, you won't have enough information to complete the calculations.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully buy in to this. If you have detailed near-field information (including phase), you can perhaps invert it. In the far-field I'm not so sure - you lose so much information.

Comment: @JonCuster Well, arguably there are no near and far fields, they're just areas where it's easy to make one assumption or another.  They're EM fields in either case.   I agree that, as you go further away, errors due to things like noise or decoherence will make the data harder and harder to process.  At some point we may draw a line in the sand and say "this is close enough to a 'far field' that we can treat this antenna like a point source" and that's the end of that logic.  But it's really more a matter of precision of measurement than a law of physics preventing it.

Comment: Put a different way perhaps, as the solid angle you measure decreases, the uncertainty goes up. Two back-to-back yagis are hard to tell from just the one pointing at you.

Comment: @JonCuster, the far field pattern is related to the fourier transform of the antenna shape. You'd have to measure the far field pattern at all angles where there's significant radiation, but you could do it. It would be a lot easier to do this way than in the near field.

Comment: On the other hand, I suspect there some duality issue, like you wouldn't be able to tell a certain yagi antenna from its dual magnetic aperture radiator. Or you wouldn't be able to tell a yagi  from a phased array of identical elements programmed to simulate a yagi.

Comment: @ThePhoton - so the easiest thing to do is practice one's direction finding and walk up to the antenna and take a picture of it...

Comment: @The Photon The far field pattern is NOT related to the antenna shape, instead the (surface) current distribution is related to it via a Fourier transform; the two are not the same even for the simplest dipole.

Comment: @hyportnex, Yes, that's a better way to put it. But usually the surface currents are related to the antenna shape in that they can only flow on surfaces of the antenna. And of course there are horn  antennas, slot antennas, etc, ...